# How to detect launch file validation failure in a script?

Tags: ros-melodic, rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to setup launch file  validation within my repo's CI using `roslaunch_add_file_check`. My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(package)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED)
catkin_package()

if (CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
    find_package(roslaunch REQUIRED)
    find_package(rostest REQUIRED)
    roslaunch_add_file_check(launch)
endif (CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)

install(DIRECTORY
  config launch
DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
```

I have some (expected) errors in my package when running the test with :

```
catkin_make --only-pkg-with-deps package
catkin_make run_tests_package
```

And the output is very clear :

> Missing package dependencies: other_package/package.xml: robot_state_publisher (notify upstream maintainer)

But when I try to check the return code of the command with :

```
echo $?
```

I get : `0`. Which means the command finished successfully.  Which makes it very hard to detect the failure in a script. Is there a way to force cmake to return a non zero code when the test fail ?

Thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385585/how-to-detect-launch-file-validation-failure-in-a-script-?/) by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 196 on 2021-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to @gvdhoorn for the answer.

Quoting the catkin tools [doc](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_build.html#building-and-running-tests) :

> For catkin packages and the run_tests
> target, failing tests will not result
> in an non-zero exit code. So if you
> want to check for failing tests, use
> the catkin_test_results command like
> this: $ catkin_test_results
> build/

---

Originally posted by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) with karma: 196 on 2021-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [ros/catkin#576](https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/576) and [catkin/catkin_tools#245](https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/245) for related discussions.

Summarising: there are people who say that you should run `catkin_test_results` to check whether testing was successful.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-09-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on 2021-09-02**:
That's the right answer thanks ! I overlooked this part in the documentation.